# Option com CSS tipo button

Tags: javascript, css

Tenho um `select`; e, no último `option`, chamo uma página.

Como não é possivel utilizar um `button` dentro de um `select`, utilizei o `onChange`.

Queria que a última `option` fosse o mais parecido com um `button` em 
CSS.

```
var select = document.querySelector('select');

select.addEventListener('change', function () {
var selecionada = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
var url = selecionada.getAttribute('data-url');
if (url) window.location = url;
});
```

HTML:

```
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option data-url="/page.htm">Button</option>
</select>
```

Comment: infelizmente, utilizando css você poderá apenas editar o background e a cor da fonte, porém você pode simular um select utilizando uma lista (ul)

Comment: Não é possível, você não pode simplesmente colocar o botão fora do <select>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente utilizar o seletor de atributos para estilizar o option que possuir o `data-url`.

Veja:

```css
select option[data-url]{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#aaa;
    text-decoration:underline;
    background:#eee;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:5px 10px;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:4px;
    margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option data-url="/page.htm">Button</option>
</select>
```

**Nota**: Fiz o teste utilizando o *Firefox 39*